# Mongoose: unable to update data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to update user data without entering all the fields like for example if I only enter **name** then only **name** gets updated other values remain same. But, when I tried doing that my **password validation** is showing error, and also saying **isAdmin is required**.

here is my thunder Client Screen:
[image]

To check whether I am getting all user data I consollLoged and I am getting every field:
[image]

Here is my code:
**userModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      match: [
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
        "Please enter a valid email address",
      ],
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      match: [
        /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
        "Password must contain minimum eight characters, atleast one letter, one number & one speccial character ",
      ],
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

// We are encrypting data before saving it
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**userController.js**

```
//  @description: Update user
//  @route:       PUT /api/users/:id
//  @access:      Private/Admin
exports.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

    if (user) {
      console.log(`USER: ${user}`);
      user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
      user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
      user.isAdmin = req.body.isAdmin;

      const updatedUser = await user.save();

      res.json({
        _id: updatedUser._id,
        name: updatedUser.name,
        email: updatedUser.email,
        isAdmin: updatedUser.isAdmin,
      });
    } else {
      const error = new Error("Sorry, user Not Found");
      error.status = 404;
      next(error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

### **UPDATE:**

I tried commenting `match` for `password` in my **userModel.js**

```
password: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  // match: [
  //   /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
  //   "Password must contain minimum eight characters, at-least one letter, one number & one special character ",
  // ],
},
```

and I am able to update the values.
[image]

What can I do so that it works with `match` as well.

Comment: Does it pass `!this.isModified("password")` in pre save hook?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry, but can you please tell me how can I check that?

Comment: `// We are encrypting data before saving it
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});`

Comment: check if it's calling `next()` and its probably a good idea to call `return after next()`, to ensure it doesn't touch password field

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in pre-save hook:

```js
// We are encrypting data before saving it
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
```

You call `next()` and the code goes further messing with `this.password` etc.
Just `return` after `next()`

```js
// We are encrypting data before saving it
    userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
      if (!this.isModified("password")) {
        next();
        return
      }

      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    });
```

You can even simplify to:

```js
// We are encrypting data before saving it
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
  }
  next()
});
```

Comment: do you mean `return next()` and if not what do I have to return?

Comment: thanks, for the try but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: check what does `this.isModified("password")` return

Comment: I thought it worked but it didn't. The `this.isModified("password")` is returning `true` even when password is not getting modefied.

Comment: Ok, so I tried removing `match: [ ],` from my password in **userModel.js** and it's working. How can I make it so that it also works with `match:[]`

Comment: Yeah, hooks are quite tricky sometimes so I would probably not use it in this password case, and just do the encryption in controller.

Comment: Also you store password as a hash, but describe it as a 8 character minimum string, this is probably not what you want, which means you don't need a match there, but must validate the password in controller/service.